# Effective Area estimation for drag calculation in coaxial quadrotor

Tags: quadcopters, multirotor, propellers, aerodynamics, drag

I have a coaxial quadrotor with a propellor size of 34 inches & i want to calculate effective rotor area for drag calculation.what will be the area whether it is summation of both upper & lower propellor disc or just the upper propellor disc area.